# Liquibase Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: oracle12c, liquibase, java-6

I am attempting to set up Liquibase 3.6.1 on a solaris VM.
My JRE is 1.6.0_151-b10.
My Liquibase.properties file is configured as follows:

```
driver:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver  
classpath:/export/home/oracle/Liquibase/lib/OJDBC-Full/ojdbc6.jar  
url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@db:port/instance  
username:uname  
password:pword
```

When calling "./Liquibase --version" (for example), I get an error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Liquibase/integration/commandline/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

I have looked around for another post relating to a similar issue with java version/Liquibase issue.  The closest I have found was relating to the "api" not being compatible with the version of java installed (version or release or update).

I apologize for the noob quality post, and I hope you folk can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquibase 3.6.1 requires minimally java 1.7.
You can find more about java versions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: I will see what I can do, but the java version isn't in my control.  Could I switch to LB 3.6.0 or something?

Comment: Also, that link has been very helpful in getting me on track previously.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help!