# Liquibase: Error java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version

Tags: liquibase

I use liquibase 3.6.1 to work with Mysql database. I use the lib "mysql-connector-java-6.0.2.jar", I got the below error when using **diff** command:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/mysql/cj/jdbc/Driver, offset=6

When I tried the lib "mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar", I got another error:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot
>   find data base driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

My command is:

> liquibase --referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://10.53.x.x/mydb
>   --referenceUsername=user --referencePassword=pass

Are there anyone can help ?

Comment: what version of java are you using?

Comment: I use Java 7 F:\Code\RAD\working_wsp\ttdp\DB\trunk>java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwi3270_27-20131115_04)
IBM J9 VM (build 2.7, JRE 1.7.0 Windows 8 x86-32 20131114_175264 (JIT enabled, A
OT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_GA_20131114_0833_B175264
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20131113_50523
GC   - R27_Java727_GA_20131114_0833_B175264
J9CL - 20131114_175264)
JCL - 20131113_01 based on Oracle 7u45-b18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are using old version of java. Liquibase 3.6.1 requires java version 1.7. Look in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027870/liquibase-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0/51028167#51028167) for more details

Comment: I use Java 7
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwi3270_27-20131115_04)
IBM J9 VM (build 2.7, JRE 1.7.0 Windows 8 x86-32 20131114_175264 (JIT enabled, A
OT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_GA_20131114_0833_B175264
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20131113_50523
GC   - R27_Java727_GA_20131114_0833_B175264
J9CL - 20131114_175264)
JCL - 20131113_01 based on Oracle 7u45-b18

Comment: Thank you. I use Liquibase 3.5.5 successful